# Error in python " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int' " for non-keyword varname?

Tags: python, list, casting

In the below function when I try to subtract the variable name  lineno with 1 it throws the type error mentioned in the question

```
     def check_Indentation():
    global Final_Slice
    global Main_Program
    c=0
    print("Final Slice values are :", Final_Slice)
    for i in range(0, len(Final_Slice)): 
        Final_Slice[i] = int(Final_Slice[i])
    for i in Final_Slice:
        print("The subtracted value is",i-1)
        indent = Main_Program[int(i)-1][1]
        if(indent>0): 
            for k in range(len(Conditionals_Output)-1, -1, -1):
                if(Conditionals_Output[k][0]<i and int(Main_Program[k][1])<indent):       
                    if(Conditionals_Output[k][0] not in Final_Slice):
                        Final_Slice.append(max) 
                        c=c+1
    Final_Slice = list(dict.fromkeys(Final_Slice))
    if(c>0):
        check_Indentation()
```

************Console Output************

> Enter the slice criteria: average,14
>
> Final Slice values are : [14, 12, 5, 11, 3]
>
> The subtracted value is 13
>
> The subtracted value is 11
>
> The subtracted value is 4
>
> The subtracted value is 10
>
> The subtracted value is 2
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\asus\eclipse-workspace\DemoSlicer\src\lex.py", line
> 193, in 
> check_Indentation()
>
> File "C:\Users\asus\eclipse-workspace\DemoSlicer\src\lex.py", line
> 168, in check_Indentation
> print("The subtracted value is",i-1) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

---

The print statement gets executed with the correct value but then throws type error after printing.

Comment: Please post the shortest version of your entire program (which other users can run verbatim), and also post the full error message you are getting.

Comment: `Final_Slice` is definitely not a set of integers. One or more of its values is a builtin method or function. What that is isn't clear from the code you pasted.

Comment: Updated the question with console output. Final_Slice contains value [14, 12, 5, 11, 3] in the above instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
Final_Slice.append(max)
```

You are adding the builtin function `max` to the Final_Slice list which means eventually you get that print statement trying to calculate `max -1` which makes no sense.

I am not sure what you mean to append here - are you trying to append the maximum value of some set of data to that list, or where you expecting to have a variable called `max` ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the variable name max to be appended to the list. But if that's the problem why am I getting error on line  print("The subtracted value is",i-1)

Comment: @AnjanaBensy - firstly you haven't defined a variable ``max`` so Python uses the max it knows - the inbuilt function. Secondly you can store functions entirely legally in Python - you can store them in lists, and dictionaries, pass them to other functions etc. The reason the print() line generates the error because that is the first point you are trying to use that item in the list.

Comment: @ TonySuffolk66 Thank you so much for pointing it out. Its working fine now. I was stuck with this error for 2 days. Max was a variable that was not needed. Some copying errors.